# How to get values from table valued function in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql

I have a program where i have to display

1. The Event Description (OpisDogodka)
2. Location (Lokacija)
3. Time (ura)
   My table valued function:

   ```
        [dbo].[DobiDogodek](
        @Ime nvarchar(100), @Datum date)
        RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (SELECT OpisDogodka AS 'Opisdogodka',Lokacija, Ura FROM Dogodek WHERE Ime=@Ime AND Datum=@Datum)
   ```

   My method to connect to the server:

   ```
    public string Dobi_dogodek(string ime,string datum)
   {
       string a="";
       cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.DobiDogodek(@Ime,@Datum)",povezava); //povezava = connectio and it succeeds to connect to the server.

       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ime", ime);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", datum); //how to pass date only?
       try
       {
           SqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           while(Reader.Read())
           {

               a = Reader.GetString(0)+" "+Reader.GetString(1)+" "+Reader.GetString(3).ToString(); // get what?

                   }
               Uspeh = true;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           ex = e;
       }
       finally
       {
           povezava.Close();
       }

       return a;
   }
   ```

   I tried also using Datatable and datarow. I am also unsure how to work with Date. I know how to work with DateTime, but I need Date and Time separate. What I am doing wrong?
   **4.6.2017 (11.40 am CET)Update**:
   It seems I get the desired result

   ```
     public List<string> Dobi_dogodek(string ime,string datum)
   {
       s = new List<string>();
       cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.DobiDogodek(@Ime,@Datum)",povezava);

       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ime", ime);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", Convert.ToDateTime(datum));
       dt = new DataTable();
       da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       da.Fill(dt);

       try
       {
           foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
           {
               s.Add(dr["Opis dogodka"].ToString() + "\\" + dr["Lokacija"].ToString() + "\\" + dr["Ura"].ToString());
           }

           Uspeh = true;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           ex = e;
       }
       finally
       {
           povezava.Close();
       }

       return s;
   }
   ```

   Now I just need to split the strings according to my requirements, but is the a better (not necessarily an easy) way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", Convert.ToDateTime(datum));`

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx .

Answer (score 0):

what is happening when you run it? are you getting an error message? is it getting it as an int? did you see what the sql server is getting from application by using sql profiler? 
I will double check but I think your problem is you are not putting quotes around your variables in our statement so when it runs it is evaluating them as ints. try `"SELECT * FROM dbo.DobiDogodek('@Ime','@Datum')"`. It been a long time since I havnt used something like EF...

Comment: The labels that should have values in it are blank. I am new in using stored procedures,  user defined fuctions and table valued functions with C#.